# Errors with VPS.ME Free

Tags: vnc, remote, ipv6

I need your help.

I'm a total noob about Linux, thats why I need you to help me by telling me what to do, step by step.

My problem is that I have only IPv6 from vps.me hosting and I want to connect via remote desktop.

I found tutorial [link](http://www.vps.me/forum/vps-hosting-tutorials/access-free-vps-me-ipv6-remote-desktop-vnc-from-ipv4-ipv6-to-ipv4-proxy) but I have some errors.

The error I am getting is:

`Error in TightVNC Viewer: Connection parameters (host,port, socket, gates) is empty`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While we want to help you solve your problems, we need you to post the errors you are getting for us to be able to help you. Also, screenshots would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I don't even know how to start. I could connect by Windows tool on other hostings but I have there IPv4 and there I havent.

Comment: Well, you can still provide us with the errors. We need those errors to be able to help you. Once you get them you can edit your post to include them.

Comment: ok then. I have installed xubuntu-destkop and vncserver. Its running but now I dont know how to connect at my PC because when I paste IPv6 in TightVNC I can see an error. "Error in TightVNC Viewer: Connection parameters (host,port, socket, gates) is empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to put brackets around the IP (read here to see: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.tight-vnc.general/6094). Syntax:

`[IPv6 ADDRESS HERE]:PORT` or `[IPv6 ADDRESS HERE]::PORT`

Short and simple, that should solve your problem!